# Extending Angular class from shared module

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is a simple illustration:
Class1.

```
import { Class2 } from '@shared/models/class2';
export class Class1 extends Class2 {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.prop1 = ...
   }
}
```

Class2

```
export class Class2 {
   prop1: number;
   constructor() {

   }
}
```

Seems like VS Code cannot resolve '@shared/models/class2' because it says, Class1 doesn't have property prop1. At the same time compiler builds with no errors. However, at the runtime the object based on that class will not have prop1. Any idea, what am I missing? My Angular version is 15.

Thanks

Comment: What is number? This code should not compile. You don't have the super() call in constructor. Please provide [mre].

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to be Angular problem, but Typescript

Comment: Not sure it's not Angular. It cannot resolve @shared.

Comment: @Vega. number is a type.

Comment: try declare prop1 as `prop1!:number` or `prop1:number=0`

Comment: Yes it is the type, but before you had = number.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Elisio. Does not look like it helped.